# Maximum limit on User Name and Password field in Mqtt CONNECT message payload

Tags: mqtt

Is there a restriction on the size of the string representing user name and password fields of the Mqtt CONNECT payload. Is it possible that we can even send a JSON string as a user name or a password. If so then what are the size restrictions if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of the username and password fields can be 65535 bytes long.

Comment: Just one more thing. Is passing a JSON string via the user name or password field considered an anti pattern or not ?

Comment: You are probably going to have to write your own broker (or at least an authentication plugin) to do anything meaningful with it